# NetBeans says upload was successfull, but remote file is not changed

Tags: netbeans, web-deployment

I created a new project from remote sources. I setup the deployment and downloaded the whole project from the FTP server via Netbeans.

I changed a file's content and uploaded it via Netbeans deployment, it says:

> ## Summary
>
> Succeeded: file      app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
>   Runtime: 194 ms, processed: 1 file(s), 3,062 KB

However, nothing actually changed. So I logged in to the FTP-Server and opened the file, but the file is still in it's initial state. So the upload never actually happened.

I also tried it via "synchronize" but it makes no difference.

How can I solve this?

---

I am using the latest version (8.2 Build 201609300101)

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version (8.2 Build 201609300101)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It was because of the "Upload Directory" setting. I somehow thought that I have to specify the upload directory where users upload their stuff, but of course I had to change it to the root directory of my project. Now it works!